# .htaccess mod-rewrite regex expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am making a `.htaccess` file with various `mod_rewrite` rules. At the moment, one of my rules is

`RewriteRule ^blog /directorypath/index.php [L]`

but when you type in `http://www.example.com/blogfjdkkfnfdjn`, it still loads the `blog` page.

Basically, I am looking for the regex for it to load the blog when JUST `/blog` is typed in and nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access your blog via `/blog` or `/blog/` then I would use

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /directorypath/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Redirect permanent /blog /directorypath/index.php
```

If you need a temporary you can use: `302` instead of `permanent`

OR

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /directorypath/index.php [R=301,L]
```

If you need a temporary you can use: `R=302`

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$` character to the expression

`RewriteRule ^blog$ /directorypath/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /directorypath/index.php [L]
```